# Docusign API - Read Only Tabs vs Edittable Tabs

Tags: docusignapi

Simple Question,

I have a document with about 100 read only text tabs, but only about 5 sign here / edittable text tabs...

In order to populate all the text tabs with the data on entry, I have had to send them with the signer(s) individually... is there a way to specify the read only text tabs as a "Document" Level... and then only use the edittable tabs in each particular signers section?

Answer (score 0):

Tabs are always set with regards to particular recipient, for document level data there are Envelope Fields but those are used for custom meta data for the envelope and not during the signing experience.

One option I'm not sure will help you or not is **Custom Fields** (not to be confused with Envelope Fields) which are recipient level tabs you can create one-time then re-use in your requests/templates. You can test them easily by editing a template and going into the Custom Tab section in tagging palette on the left.

[image]

As you can see you can set the **Initial Value** and also make it **Read Only** then save the Custom Tab.  Then in your code you can reference this tab where needed for your recipients to save some legwork.

Comment: Can the API modify the Custom Fields? Right now, I have "custom fields" as Read Only Text Tabs, that I send data to the document... Would it be wiser to use custom fields for that information, and use TextTabs as things that are modified by the individual recipients?

My issue, is that I want all recipients to be able to see the data on the Custom Fields, but say there's "2" different places to sign... must I send the custom fields through both recipients, or can they be placed on the envelope level, without having to send it 2x ... once for each recipient?

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign tabs need to be assigned to the recipients only, you cannot have DS Tabs on the envelope without assigning it to a recipient. If I understood your query, then you have multiple recipients on the envelope at the same routing order and each recipient should see the pre-populated data for each read only DS Tab on the document before signing. If yes, then there is one setting at an account level which will burnt the DS tab value on the document before any signer will start the signing ceremony. If you go to Admin --> Sending and Signing Section --> Sending Settings --> then select `When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field for all recipients`. With this setting enabled all recipients at the same routing order will be able to see the values of these read only tabs pre-populated from your application.